# Use min-height for p to get same height cross browsers

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, css

a basic question.

I set p { height: 25px ; min-height 25px;} to get the same line height in a form.
I works in fine in most browsers.

But when I invisible html tags inside p, the p will keep the blank space (25px)

is there an alternative css for min-height, to make it work in IE and other browsers? since p always contains html inputs (label, textbox).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<p>` element will maintain the 25px space if you set the tags inside it to invisible because you have set the height on the element.

If you are trying to hide sections of the form you will have to hide the wrapping `<p>` element and not the contents.